# How to make custom time and date?

Tags: date, time, clock

I have looked at [this](http://www.imperial-library.info/) code and they just seem to simply update theirs every day with the HTML, but I know there's a way to make a custom date by altering Monday to be Morndas, Sunday to be Sundas, January as Morning Star, etc. How would I go about coding this for my own website, as it's a cool little feature to have on an Elder Scrolls website, and I am not always available to update it every night at midnight.

Thanks

Comment: The miracles of server side scripting. Do you have PHP? You can do it in Javascript too, of course..

Comment: I've no idea how to do that. Mind showing me? Javascript is preferred

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is best done using server side scripting, like PHP. But below I've given a Javascript implementation which you can easily embed. Once you learn about server side scripting, it should be trivial to translate this code to another language.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Function to determine the postfix of the month number
  function numberPostFix(nr) {
    nr = nr % 100;
    if (nr >= 10 && nr < 20) return 'th';
    nr = nr % 10;
    if (nr == 1) return 'st';
    if (nr == 2) return 'nd';
    if (nr == 3) return 'rd';
    return 'th';
  }

  // Arrays of custom month names.
  var monthNames = [
    "Morning Star",
    "Sun's Dawn",
    "First Seed",
    "Rain's Hand",
    "Second Seed",
    "Mid Year",
    "Sun's Height",
    "Last Seed",
    "Hearthfire",
    "Frostfall",
    "Sun's Dusk",
    "Evening Star"
  ];
  // Array of custom weekday names.
  var dayNames = [
    "Sundas",
    "Morndas",
    "Tirdas",
    "Middas",
    "Turdas",
    "Fredas",
    "Loredas"
  ];

  // Get all relevant parts.
  var date = new Date();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var monthday = date.getDate();
  var weekday = date.getDay();

  // Construct the day text.
  var dateHtml = "Today is " + dayNames[weekday] + ", " + monthday + "<sup>" + numberPostFix(monthday) + "</sup> of " + monthNames[month];

  // Write to document.
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = dateHtml;
});
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Welcome, this is your page header.</h2>
  <span id="date"></span>
</header>
```